# Trouble downloading S3 bucket objects through boto3. Error 403 HeadObject: Forbidden

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm aware there are other threads on here about this issue but am still struggling to find the right solution. I am attempting to download a set of specific objects within an S3 bucket (that I do have access to) using the following python script. When running the script, the first object successfully downloads but then this error (403) is thrown:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

See below my code:

```
import csv
import boto3
import re
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

prod_number_array_bq = []
prod_number_array_s3 = []
with open('bq-results-20191218-151637-rshujisvqrri.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        sliced = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str(row))
        prod_number_array_bq.append(sliced)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('********')

for key in bucket.objects.all():
    sliced = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str(key.key))
    if((set(sliced) & set(prod_number_array_bq))!=""):
            bucket.download_file(key.key,sliced + '.txt')
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you don't have permission to HEAD the object in question. Check the ownership of the object (is it owned by another AWS account?) If that looks OK, do you have any S3 bucket policy, IAM policy, or S3 object ACL that would restrict your credentials for that object?

Answer (score 7):

Typically when you see a 403 on `HeadObject` despite having the `s3:GetObject` permission, it's because the `s3:ListObjects` permission wasn't provided for the bucket **AND** your key doesn't exist. It's a security measure to prevent exposing information about what objects are or aren't in your bucket. When you have both the `s3:GetObject` permission for the objects in a bucket, and the `s3:ListObjects` permission for the bucket itself, the response for a non-existent key is a 404 "no such key" response. If you only have `s3:GetObject` permission and request a non-existent object, the response is a 403 "access denied".

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I could read the file but couldn't download it

So I the following would have printed the file information

```
resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=origin)
print(resp)
```

but then this would have given `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden` error

```
s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, origin, destination)
```

The problem was the model was uploaded from different AWS account. We were missing ACL on upload. so,

so we uploaded the file with the following command

```
s3_client.upload_file(origin,
                      bucket_name,
                      destination,
                      ExtraArgs={'ACL':'bucket-owner-full-control'})
```

and this led us to read and download the file as we expectd.